# Content inside .each in click function only being called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I ran into a problem today while coding a menu opening animation.

On click of the menu button, the menu opens and the elements inside it get a class added to them (making them fade in).

By clicking the menu button again, the menu closes and the class is removed from all elements, resulting in them fading out again.

Unfortunately, the adding classes to the elements only works once.
Opening and closing the menu works, but the content inside the .each function inside openMenu() seems to only run once and then not again. The addClass on the menuMain,White and Lightblue still works.

Unfortunately none of my attempts to fix the problem worked out so far. I'd greatly appreciate if someone has an idea why this is happening and how I can enable the content inside the .each inside openMenu() to run multiple times.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
/* ...Other Code... */

const menuMain = $('.menu');
const menuWhite = $('.menu__bg.white');
const menuLightblue = $('.menu__bg.lightblue');
const menuCircle = $('.menu__bg-circle')
const menuLinks = $('.menu-links')

function openMenu() {
    $(menuMain).addClass('open'); /* works! */
    $(menuWhite).addClass('open'); /* works! */
    $(menuLightblue).addClass('open'); /* works! */
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(menuLinks).each(function(i) { /* works only ONCE */
            console.log('test');
            $(this).delay(100*i).queue( function() { /* Staggered adding of Class */
                $(this).addClass('visible');
            });
        });
        $(menuCircle).addClass('visible'); /* works! */
    }, 500); /* .open has 500ms transition, classes are only added after menu is fully open. */
};

function closeMenu() {
    $(menuMain).removeClass('open'); /* works! */
    $(menuWhite).removeClass('open'); /* works! */
    $(menuLightblue).removeClass('open'); /* works! */
    $(menuCircle).removeClass('visible'); /* works! */
    $(menuLinks).each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('visible')) {
            $(this).removeClass('visible');
        };
    });
};

$('.menu__button').on('click', function() {
   var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
   if (clicks) {
      $("body").css("overflow-y", "auto");
      animationMenu.setDirection(-1); /* Lottie Animation */
      animationMenu.play(); /* Lottie Animation */
      closeMenu();
   } else {
      $("body").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
      animationMenu.setDirection(1); /* Lottie Animation */
      animationMenu.play(); /* Lottie Animation */
      openMenu();
   }
   $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A little tip: You can right click -> inspect and then press Console at the top. This will show you any errors in your web page.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE thank you, but there is no error shown. Otherwise the fix would have been quite obvious.

Comment: Since it's not a syntax error, it's a logic error. Try using some console logging to see what worked and what didn't.

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery, I would rewrite your element variables as `const menuMain = $('.menu');` these will behave more predictably with the rest of your jQuery code

Comment: You want to be careful mixing DOM methods like `querySelector` and jQuery. Typically jQuery re-queries when selecting elements, whereas `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` do not.

Comment: Also, try using `$('.someselector').on('click', function() {...})` as opposed `.click()` as it is deprecated.

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic thank you, I did not think about that actually. Changed it now and saved quite a bit of code :) Did not fix the problem, but makes it look cleaner at least!

Comment: Does it work as expected (except for the initial delay) if you comment out the setTimeout part?  Could you not add 500 to each delay and skip setTimeout entirely?

Comment: Try capturing your variables INSIDE open/close functions you might be saving them before they have the right classes for you to operate on.

Comment: Please include the HTML and CSS on which this code runs in a [mre]. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar). That way we can see what's going on.

Comment: I would suggest moving away from this logic entirely. It is fragile in that if someone closes the menu before it's done opening, you're left in with an unpredictable outcome. (the reverse may also be true)

Comment: @KevinB I thought about that too, but I am quite new to jquery/javascript. Do you have a suggestion on how I should go about that problem? Or where I could get more information on how to write it better?

Comment: I'm not one to really mess with animations often, but, i wouldn't mix the two. Do the entire animation in css, or in javascript, so that you can easily interrupt either as needed without needing to worry with a mixture of setTimeouts and animation queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another few tries I finally got it, and it was actually quite the easy fix to be honest.
The problem was the queue function. The elements get queued in the first menu open, so they can not be queued again.
Adding a $(this).dequeue(); after the $(this).addClass('visible'); fixed it, since now each element is dequeued after the class add is done and is ready to be queued again.

```
$(menuLinks).each(function(i) {
        console.log(i);
        $(this).delay(100*i).queue( function() {
            $(this).addClass('visible');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    });
```